# How to add npm ckeditor4 in stenciljs?

Tags: ckeditor4.x, stenciljs

I have installed npm i ckeditor4 to my stencil project and I have used it like this. But Im not getting the ckeditor, tell me where to add the script tag I am completely new to stencil

ui-editor.tsx

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
    tag: 'ui-editor',
    styleUrl: 'style.scss',
    shadow: true
})

export class UiEditor {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="editor">
                <p>This is the editor content.</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As said in the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor4 where should I add the scripts

```
<script src="./node_modules/ckeditor4/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the script tag from your index.html file. The following component will automatically add the script tag from unpkg.

[Example on webcomponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/DVYy1rUAcEXsz2T3p7PR)

```js
import { h, Component, State, Host } from "@stencil/core";

@Component({
  tag: "ck-editor"
})
export class CkEditor {
  _textarea: HTMLTextAreaElement;

  componentWillLoad() {
    return this.appendScript();
  }

  componentDidLoad() {
    //@ts-ignore
    let editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this._textarea, {
      width: "99%",
      height: "300px",
    });
  }

  private async submit() {
    // @ts-ignore
    console.log(
      CKEDITOR.instances[
        this._textarea.nextSibling.id.replace("cke_", "")
      ].getData()
    );
  }

  appendScript() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (document.getElementById("ckeditor-script")) {
        resolve();
        return;
      }
      const ckeditorScript = document.createElement("script");
      ckeditorScript.id = "ckeditor-script";
      ckeditorScript.src = "https://unpkg.com/ckeditor4@4.14.1/ckeditor.js";
      ckeditorScript.onload = () => resolve();
      document.body.appendChild(ckeditorScript);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <textarea ref={(el) => (this._textarea = el)}></textarea>
        <button onClick={() => this.submit()}>Submit</button>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

You should be able to import ckeditor but I haven't tested to see how that handles in rollup. The project I was recently working on was already loading ckeditor from unpkg so we went that direction instead.